# Mobile device + Facebook comments not working

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I have installed facebook comments in my Joomla website but in android and iOS devices view is messed up, you can see only like 10% of comment box [image: AS you can see in the picture]

I've tried searching possible solutions but I've found no luck. Another point is that if you set android browser to desktop mode, it works superb, but on simple mode, random thing appears.

To be clear pic is taken with android ICS 4.04 joomla 1.5 version. To preview site is jeffrivera.com

Answer (score 0):

Facebook comments look fine on TechCrunch, so I suspect its your website's formatting that is making it look weird.  Got a link to your site?  Can you also paste the relevant HTML that contains the Facebook Comments plugin?

[image]